# !("(").equals(stack.peek()) not working properly

Tags: java, stack

Recently I've been working on creating a calculator by implementing a stack in java. I've run into some trouble with `stack.peek().equals("(")` in my code and I have tried a few different methods to solve this issue but nothing seems to work.

Here is my code below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;
public class URCalculator {

    public static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static Stack<String> uRStack = new Stack<String>();
    public static Stack<String> uROPStack = new Stack<String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        prompt();
        String val = scan.next();

        pusher(splitInput(val));
        while(!uRStack.empty()) {
            System.out.println(uRStack.pop());
        }
    }
    public static String[] splitInput(String val) {
        return val.split("(?!^)");
    }

    public static void pusher(String[] s) {
        int counter = 0; // counter determines if there is a numeric value     
in the index prior, if so then we concatenate and add back to the stack.
        for(int i=0; i<s.length; i++) { // loops through split input array 
            if(isNumeric(s[i]) && counter != 0) { // checks if number and if 
previous number 
                pushNumeric(uRStack.pop() + s[i]);
                counter++;
            }
            else if (isNumeric(s[i])) { // checks if just a number
                pushNumeric(s[i]);
                counter++;
            }
            else if(isOperator(s[i])) { // if not number  then reset counter for latter values
                addOperator(s[i]);
                counter=0;
            }           
        }
        uRStack.push(uROPStack.pop());

     }
    public static void addOperator(String s) { // uses cases to determine logic for operator stack
    switch(s) {
    case "+": 

        if(!uROPStack.empty()){
            while(!"(".equals(uROPStack.peek()) && !uROPStack.empty()) { // while operators not of lower precedence then push pop
                uRStack.push(uROPStack.pop());
            }
        }
        uROPStack.push(s);
        break;

    case "-":

        if(!uROPStack.empty()){
            while(!"(".equals(uROPStack.peek()) && !uROPStack.empty()) { // while operators not of lower precedence then push pop
                uRStack.push(uROPStack.pop());
            }
        }
        uROPStack.push(s);
        break;

    case "*":

        if(!uROPStack.empty()) {
            while("*".equals(uROPStack.peek()) || !"/".equals(uROPStack.peek())) { // while operators of equal or greater precedence then push pop
                uRStack.push(uROPStack.pop());
            }
        }
        uROPStack.push(s);
        break;

    case "/":

        if(!uROPStack.empty()) {
            while("*".equals(uROPStack.peek()) || !"/".equals(uROPStack.peek())) { // while operators of equal or greater precedenc then push pop
                uRStack.push(uROPStack.pop());
            }
        }
        uROPStack.push(s);
        break;

    case "(":

        uROPStack.push(s);
        break;

    case ")":
        if(!uROPStack.empty()){
            while(!"(".equals(uROPStack.peek())) {
                uRStack.push(uROPStack.pop());
            }
        }
        break;

    }

}
```

I have added my main and pusher methods for context, but the real issue lies in the addOperation method, specifically the first boolean within the while loop. The error I get is posted below:

```
    Hello and welcome to the URCalculator. Please type an operation
    1-2-3-4-5
    Exception in thread "main" java.util.EmptyStackException
    at java.util.Stack.peek(Unknown Source)
    at URCalculator.addOperator(URCalculator.java:129)
    at URCalculator.pusher(URCalculator.java:107)
    at URCalculator.main(URCalculator.java:14)
```

I understand my code is not the most elegant of the sorts, nor is it finished, but I can't seem to understand why I'm receiving the error I'm getting. One thing I have checked is that when I remove the `!"(".equals(uROPStack.peek())`
from the expression entirely, things seem to run smoothly. The problem is that I still need to handle the paranthetical case in my stack so I don't know what to do.

Comment: You cannot peek an empty stack. You need to check first if it's empty. That is, flip the conditions: `!uROPStack.empty() && !"(".equals(uROPStack.peek())`

Comment: @janos thank you so much that was exactly the problem1

Comment: You're welcome, I made that an answer, with more explanations and other tips. If it answered your question, then perhaps you can mark it the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This condition is broken:

> ```
> !"(".equals(uROPStack.peek()) && !uROPStack.empty()
> ```

If `uROPStack` is empty, then `uROPStack.peek()` will throw `EmptyStackException`.

If you flip the conditions, it will work as intended:

```
!uROPStack.empty() && !"(".equals(uROPStack.peek())
```

Here, thanks to the short-circuiting behavior of the `&&` operator,
if the first condition is false (= the stack is empty),
then the second condition (the `.peek()`) will not be executed,
and you get the desired behavior.

---

You didn't ask about it, but another problem is waiting to explode here too:

> ```
> if(!uROPStack.empty()) {
>     while("*".equals(uROPStack.peek()) || !"/".equals(uROPStack.peek())) { 
>         uRStack.push(uROPStack.pop());
>     }
> }
> ```

That is, since you `uROPStack.pop()` in the body of the `while` loop,
the `uROPStack.peek()` in the loop condition may lead to `EmptyStackException`. You need to make sure the stack is not empty in the loop condition:

```
while(!uROPStack.peek().isEmpty() && ("*".equals(uROPStack.peek()) || !"/".equals(uROPStack.peek()))) {
```